# Rails way to hide a new instance of a model that is not saved to the database yet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a `Book` resource and a `Comment` resource that belongs to `Book`.

On `app/views/book/show.html.erb`, I show the book information and all the comments for the book. A user can add comments directly from that page.

So the `BooksController#show` action looks like this:

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

And the `app/views/book/show.html.erb` looks like this:

```
# ... book info from @book

<%= form_for [@book, @comment] do |f| %>
# ... rest of the form_for

<% @book.comments.each do |comment| %>
# ... print all the comments
```

So this goes to `CommentsController#create` action:

```
def create
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id]
  @comment = @book.comments.new(comment_params)

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @book
  else
    render 'book/show'
  end
end
```

Now all this is good, but when this action fails and renders `book/show`, I can see the new comment in the comments list, because it's added to that book's comments collection, even though it's not saved to the database yet.

What's the rails way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a scope to only render persisted comments

#### app/models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :persisted, -> { where "id IS NOT NULL" }
end
```

#### app/views/book/show.html.erb

```
<% @book.comments.persisted.each do |comment| %>
```

Comment: That's one way, but then I need to remember to use `persisted` everywhere, I'm hoping there's a simpler and more idiomatic way to do this. But yeah, this definitely would work.

Comment: You could make it the default scope but that comes with its own [problems](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try redirecting to book/show instead of rendering it directly.

Instead of your conditional, just always redirect. You may want to inform the user of errors though, so you can set a flash message.

```
if @comment.save
  redirect_to @book
else
  redirect_to @book, :flash => { :error => "Something went wrong!" }
end
```

Comment: This is not actually a great solution as you'd lose any inline validation on the comment form.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your comment differently:

```
def create
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id]
  @comment = @comments.new(comment_params.merge { book_id: @book.id })

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @book
  else
    render 'book/show'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I first tried using the following in the `app/views/books/show.html.erb`:

```
<% @book.reload.comments.each do |comment| %>
# ... print all the comments
```

This reloads the `book` object from the database so the new comment that is not saved to the database yet is not shown. But the downside is that this hits the database one more time, which is unnecessary.

So I ended up using this:

```
<% @book.comments.select(&:persisted?).each do |comment| %>
# ... print all the comments
```

This only shows the persisted comments.

I'll probably take this logic off the view template, and put it in a view helper.